# Stubbing a C function that has a a parameter with the same name in C++

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing

```
 int stat(const char *__restrict__ __file, struct stat *__restrict__ __buf);
```

This function needs to be stubbed in order to cover more branches in an unit test made using Google Unit Test.

**In file stubs.h**

I have to stub this function, so I provide the following prototype:

```
int stat_stub(const char *__restrict__ __file, struct stat *__restrict__ __buf);
```

Followed by:

```
#define stat stat_stub
int stat_RET;
```

**Implementation in stubs.c**

```
int stat_stub(const char *__restrict__ __file, struct stat *__restrict__ __buf)
{
    return stat_RET;
}
```

The problem is that the define also replaces **struct stat** with **struct stat_stub**, and this causes a multitude of errors to appear when compiling.

I would like to know if there is a workaround to this issue, as I am currently stuck on it.

Comment: Don't use macros!

Comment: Please provide an alternative then.

Comment: Note that your stub violates reserved identifier rules. Since you don't use the parameters, it's perhaps simpler to not name them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a macro with parameters.

```
#define stat(p1,p2) stat_stub(p1,p2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use macros at all, instead you can make it differ in build system.

---

Remove `stubs.h` and only use real header in production code.

In `stubs.c` define function with the same name:

```
int stat(const char *__restrict__ __file, struct stat *__restrict__ __buf)
{
    return stat_RET;
}
```

Now, when building production target, you link real implementation. For UT target, you build and link `stubs.c`.

This solution will be more versatile than macros and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The root of all your problems is that you name types and functions the same thing. Simply don't do that, unless this is a C++ constructor. It doesn't look like one. The only reason this code compiles in C, is because C uses different namespaces for struct tags and function identifiers.

The solution to all your problems is not to use macros or other work-arounds, but to implement a coding standard for how you name types and functions.

Comment: `stat` is a POSIX function and `struct stat` is also from POSIX. So there's no option to not use those names if you need to use that function. C++ has a language hack to allow this kind of naming, and it was driven specifically by `stat`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Why am I not surprised... POSIX considered harmful.